# Debug Angular-CLI app accross Visual Studio Code not on localhost:4200

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

All!

How enable debug mode in Visual Studio Code for Angular-CLI application with arbitrary url. 
With default ng serve url (localhost:4200) it works fine.
With another url breakpoints are set but not bound.

Here's vscode launch.config

```
{
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///./*":"${workspaceRoot}/*"
        },
        "url": "http://localhost/CountrySite/v2/",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
```

[app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24Vn.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in 401 response for js-sourcemaps returned from web server.
Solved

Comment: For some cases my web-server did not allow the downloading of js-sourcemaps from webRoot folder.
Added webRoot to white-list